# Python - Kivy, Have I Structured this wrong?

Tags: python, kivy

At the moment I have one Floatlayout in SHeditorMain, Inside the class SHeditormain i've declared a bunch of widgets (buttons, popups, labels, etc..) and used self.add_widget to add them.

Now i want to create a new window that opens up inside/over the FloatLayout and i can't seem to get it to works. All the examples i've seen so far regarding multiple windows is either using App as main class for the creation of widgets inside the layouts. Any suggestions or do i have to restructure the code?

```
class SHeditorMain(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SHeditorMain, self).__init__(**kwargs)as
        self.add_widget(blabla)
        self.add_widget(blabla)
        self.add_widget(blabla)
        self.add_widget(blabla)
        self.dbconnection = DBconnection()

        #declare popups etc


    def functionEvents(self, instance):
        yaddayadda

    def functionEvents(self, instance):
        yaddayadda

    def functionEvents(self, instance):
        yaddayadda


class SHeditor(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = SHeditorMain()
        return self.root
```

Comment: What is this ,,new window'' supposed to do? Under which conditions it should appear?

Comment: When you press a button inside the FloatLayout you open the new "window"  where inside it you can edit values contained in the SHeditorMain instance. e.g. If i had a button with the text "hello world" i could change the text to whatever.

Comment: You need the Popup widget, which can be found under the kivy.uix.popup module. Read the documentation and the examples to get a grasp of it.

Comment: I've got a couple of Popups working fine, what i really want is a new "window". At worst i'll settle for a new popup. I think the popup will be really cramped with stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38057351/5994041) about multiple "windows" and why it may not be desired. I can recommend you to have kivy window maximized and using ModalView as a pseudo-form that can be dragged and has some button that would close it. More control over everything, cleaner code, beginner friendly. Create a custom widget that inherits from ModalView and what it does is up to you.

You can place modals wherever you want them to be - look into popup source code in [repo](https://github.com/kivy/kivy) how the positions are set. You'll basically end up with a custom Popup that you can control without crippling the original widget.

Another way may be to use ScreenManager(or PageLayout, Carousel, xyz other widgets) which provide mobile-/presentation-like view. The sooner you get to kv language, the sooner you'll have less troubles to imagine that stuff out of pocket e.g. you see a fancy app, you can open [kivy-designer](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer) or for more control/less fancy go for [KivyCatalog](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/demo/kivycatalog) and just type what you see that's how straightforward the kvlang is.

**Example with Modals:**(old attempt to create windows-like... something via Kivy = FloatLayout with Scatter(only drag enabled) as "windows")

[image]

Which leads me to the conclusion that if you think you *need* multiple windows or *another* window would be nice for whatever reason but you are not sure if it'd work or something - you actually **don't** and you are overcomplicating things, which steal your attention from the important parts of your code to UI.

(PS, I'd edit the answer mentioned at the top, but in that question user has a little bit more complicated problem)